# Why isn't my subview loading?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a project with 3 .xib files, MainMenu, FileUploadView, FileBrowseView.

- MainMenu has a NSPanel, it's owner is AppDelegate, and AppDelegate has an outlet to NSPanel called FilePanel.  The NSView below the NSPanel is called filePanelView and also has an outlet in AppDelegate.
- FileUploadView is an NSView, it's owner is FileUploadViewController.  It has an outlet called uploadView in the controller.
- FileBrowseView is similar, owner is FileBrowseViewController, has an outlet called browseView.

So in App delegate I have the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    fileBrowseViewController = [[FileBrowseViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"FileBrowseView" bundle:nil];  
}

- (IBAction)importHandsClicked:(id)sender {
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [filePanel setIsVisible:YES];
    [filePanelView addSubview:[fileBrowseViewController browseView]]; 

}
```

The action does make filePanel visible, but it doesn't add the browseView to it.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If fileBrowseViewController is a property, try `self.fileBrowseViewController = [[FileBrowseViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"FileBrowseView" bundle:nil];`

Comment: that didn't have any effect... I also tried adding self. to [filePanelView addSubview:[self.fileBrowseViewController browseView]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that `[fileBrowseViewController browserView]` is not `nil`.

This is highly probably, especially **if you forgot or failed to link your `browseView` IBOutlet to the actual UIView** that represents your `FileBrowseView` instance in InterfaceBuilder.

*[EDIT]*
For more info about connecting outlets, [see Apple's InterfaceBuilder Help here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CreatingOutlet.html) (including tutorial video).

Comment: Thanks Ali, it actually is nil.  but how do I connect browseView to UIView?  I dragged from the browseView nib "Referencing Outlets" to the root NSView (this isn't UIKit it's a Cocoa app).

Comment: Ctrl-Drag from your FileBrowseViewController instance in InterfaceBuilder to your browserView instance, and choose the `browseView` IBoutlet. See this IB Help page which details the procedure in video: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/CreatingOutlet.html